# How to enable Explicit API mode for maven based Kotlin projects?

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlin-maven-plugin

I would like to enable [Explicit API mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#explicit-api-mode-for-library-authors) for my Kotlin project. However, I cannot find a way how to do it. On the site, I can see only `gradle` based configuration:

```
kotlin {    
    // for strict mode
    explicitApi() 
    // or
    explicitApi = ExplicitApiMode.Strict
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you're using `kotlin-maven-plugin`, so you can pass additional arguments to compiler like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>...</executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xexplicit-api=strict</arg> <!-- Enable explicit api mode -->
            ...
        </args>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

more info can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#specifying-compiler-options